# CruiseControl unable to open connection in Guest OS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox, cruisecontrol

I want to run CruiseControl 2.8.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 running in VirtualBox 4.0.12.  When I start CruiseControl with default options, it is unable to open a connection to port 8080 for the dashboard.  Port forwarding didn't make a difference, but I am not trying to access it from outside anyway.

```
2011-08-03 19:09:45,466 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpMethodDirector - Attempt number 1 to process request
2011-08-03 19:09:45,466 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpConnection   - enter HttpConnection.open()
2011-08-03 19:09:45,467 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpConnection   - Open connection to localhost:8080
2011-08-03 19:09:45,500 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpConnection   - enter HttpConnection.closeSockedAndStreams()
2011-08-03 19:09:45,501 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpMethodDirector - Closing the connection.
2011-08-03 19:09:45,501 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpConnection   - enter HttpConnection.close()
2011-08-03 19:09:45,501 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpConnection   - enter HttpConnection.closeSockedAndStreams()
2011-08-03 19:09:45,502 [Timer-0  ] INFO  HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
2011-08-03 19:09:45,514 [Timer-0  ] DEBUG HttpMethodDirector - Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:266)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.report.BuildLoopStatusReportTask.run(BuildLoopStatusReportTask.java:90)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.report.BuildLoopStatusReportTask.run(BuildLoopStatusReportTask.java:75)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:534)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:484)
2011-08-03 19:09:45,525 [Timer-0  ] INFO  HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
```

I am running cruisecontrol on a new user account I created, and I have set the same privileges as the main account I setup on Ubuntu.
Just to see if it was a firewall issue, I tried Jetty 7 with default settings and it was able to connect on port 8080.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.....

Niraj

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem... its because I had not setup the reporting tool under Tomcat, which I did, built and deployed reporting jar in local instance and the errors are gone.  I thought that cruisecontrol would kick off the jetty server for reporting too.

Niraj